# GTK3 combobox without entry moving to after GTK3 combobox with entry. Why?

Tags: python, combobox, gtk, gtk3, display

So, I've been developing this application for work, that essentially allows the user to select their department, building, and floor.  This brings up a floor plan of the selected location, where they can select different printers on that floor plan.  It also brings up another combobox where they can select by name, the printer.  I've created the comboboxes in order of how I want them to display: Department, Building, Floor, Printer.  They don't display that way though.  This is how they display instead: [ComboBox Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03doh.png).  I'm guessing this is because  the Floor combobox is a Gtk.ComboBoxText object, instead of just Gtk.ComboBox like the rest of them.  Is there a way to fix this or work around it?

```
    # Department Combo
    self.department_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(self.logic.get_department_store())
    self.department_combo.set_entry_text_column(0)
    self.combo_rowbox.pack_start(self.department_combo, False, False, 0)
    self.department_combo.show()
    # Building Combo
    self.building_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_entry()
    self.building_combo.set_entry_text_column(0)
    self.combo_rowbox.pack_start(self.building_combo, False, False, 0)
    self.building_combo.hide()
    # Floor Combo
    self.floor_combo = Gtk.ComboBoxText()
    self.floor_combo.set_entry_text_column(0)
    self.combo_rowbox.pack_start(self.floor_combo, False, False, 0)
    self.floor_combo.hide()
    # Printer Combo
    self.printer_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_entry()
    self.printer_combo.set_entry_text_column(0)
    self.combo_rowbox.pack_start(self.printer_combo, True, True, 0)
    self.printer_combo.hide()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `self.combo_rowbox` is `Gtk.Box` I would suggest changing the `pack_start` used for `self.printer_combo` to `pack_end`. This means that the widget is added on the right side of the `Box` instead of the left side.

Alternatively you could also try using a `Gtk.Grid` as the container for your `ComboBox`'s it is less flexible but helps to get a more predictable result.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I don't know why I didn't think about using pack_end...  guess I've just been so used to using pack_start.  Thanks again.

Comment: This is a good answer, although I'm not sure why the `Box` would do this, as it seems like unwanted and unexpected behavior. They should be packed in the order you pack them.

Comment: It is indeed weird behavior, I tried to reproduce it but that didn't work. It is possible that OP has created the snippet by copy pasting from the original code and corrected his mistake by doing so. (At first I thought it might had to do with the hide and show but this isn't the case)

Comment: I made this all by hand (no copy and pasting)...  if I ever figure out what was causing it, I'll let you guys know.